# How to use SearchView in the toolbar on clicking search icon

Tags: android, searchview

I am working on the following screen:

**1 Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Here on the toolbar ,i am having a search icon.To add this search icon ,i have used the following code:

**menu_friend_list_activity.xml**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>
```

**Code inside Activity**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_friend_list_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_search:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

On clicking search icon i want to display the SearchView in toolbar(if i am not wrong here).In short i want to implement the following screen:

[image: Sceenshot]

Please tell me how can i implement this.Search will be different for different fragments.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_actions, menu);

            MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchViewItem.getActionView();
            searchView.setQueryHint("Search for Product,Brands...");
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);// Do not iconify the widget; expand it by defaul

            SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    // This is your adapter that will be filtered
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"textChanged :"+newText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return true;
                }

                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    // **Here you can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.**

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"searchvalue :"+query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return true;
                }
            };
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener); 

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not inflating the menu correctly, Here is how your supposed to inflate it to get the screen you want

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.yourmenyxml, menu);

    item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
```

Comment: I have a similar problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702055/android-how-do-i-get-searchview-close-button-to-return-to-search-edittext?noredirect=1#comment74449117_43702055.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. and I solved as following:

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.ot_action_search);
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

searchItem.expandActionView();
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.setQuery(searchQuery, false);
```

NB: the expandActionView() should be invoked on searchItem menu item not on the searchView. that was my mistake.